# Android - fill html form and invoke submit

Tags: android, html, forms, submit, fill

Is it possible to invoke a html form submission without user interaction? I know that it's possible to make a post request via HttpClient, that doesn't solve my problem though.
I need to fill some form input fields on a webpage programmatically, then "click" on the submit button. So the first time user launches the app, he will provide these data through EditText fields and the app will save them. Than every other time the app will launch, that form will be filled and submitted by the app on background. Perhaps I could use HtmlUnit, but I read, that it's shifty to get it working on android.
FYI: The form on the website is a login form. It includes some hidden inputs with generated data, so that's why I can't use the HttpClient. I wouldn't know what data to put in.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do DOM manipulation via a webview, so that's out.

You can use HTTPClient for the method I'm going to describe, I highly suggest you check out [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), which is much simpler to use in this case. You can grab the HTML of the page (to get the generated data) and then send a post request to submit the form. All of this can be done programmatically. There's also a lot of doc's and questions on JSoup on stack.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a fast reply. I will try it right away.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I had the same problem (how to form-fill then submit in a versatile way) and thought I'd share this.

Salendroid is a good solution and well supported: http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html

Seems to cover all of the basic interactions at least. No fuss.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just used WebView. I filled and submitted the form with javascript using WebView.loadUrl("javascript_code"). 
 I will still use JSoup for parsing the html, so thanks for that.